# $gcd(p,m-1)=gcd(p-1,m)=1$ if and only if G has a normal Sylow p-subgroup in $Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Suppose that $|G|=pm$ where $p$ is a prime and $p\not|m$.
>
> Prove that $gcd(p-1,m)=gcd(p,m-1)=1$ iff G has a normal Sylow p-subgroup in $Z(G)$

I have a problem in both directions.

How can I solve this problem with Sylow theorem?

Comment: This is false, for example, if $p=3$, $m=2$,  and $G$ is  the cyclic group of order $6$. Then $\gcd(p-1,m) = 2 \ne 1$, but $G$ has a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup in $Z(G)=G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, my problem is wrong. How about left to right? Is it also false?

Comment: If $P \in Syl_p(G)$ with $P \subseteq Z(G)$, then by Schur-Zassenhaus $P$ has a complement $H$ that is automatically normal, since $P$ is central. Hence $G=H \times P$.

Comment: Yes, left to right is also false.